# AngularJS callback function implementation

Tags: angularjs

I need to execute code that will be executed after a function has finished executing. I've read about $q, then, etc. and all the examples make use of directives or services. Here's what I have:

```
$scope.myFunction = function () {
    $scope.func1();
    // some other code
};

<div ng-click="myFunction()">Click Here</div>
```

I don't want to execute "some other code" until after `$scope.func1()` has executed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.func1.$inject = ['$q'];
$scope.func1 = function($q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    //sync or async code
        defer.resolve();

    return defer.promise;
};

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.func1().then(function() {
        //some other code
    });
};
```